# SPARQL same indi

Tags: group-by, rdf, sparql

Can SPARQL be used to find subjects having identical objects for a given predicate. Considering a class Variable with data property as
Variable--hasvalue-->Integer, if there are five instances such as

> 1. a ----hasvalue------> 2
> 2. b ----hasvalue------> 1
> 3. c ----hasvalue------> 2
> 4. d ----hasvalue------> 0
> 5. e ----hasvalue------> 1

How to extract a and c has same value whereas b and e has same value. Group option works in grouping as above, but is it possible to extract subjects corresponding to each grouped objects.

Comment: You just need to find what "2" in your ontology is and then write a query. Something like ?x ?y :2. Read the SPARQL manual, this is the first thing they teach.

Comment: The wiki text for [tag:group-by] says "

GROUP BY is a command in the SQL relational database standard for collapsing result rows that share a common field value into a single row. Aggregate functions can be performed on other fields in the group, such as SUM() or AVG(), to collate related data into a single value. " You're not asking about SQL, though, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's always easier to write example code if you provide sample data to work with.  Please provide sample data in the future.  Your suggested data looks like this:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :hasValue 2 .
:b :hasValue 1 .
:c :hasValue 2 .
:d :hasValue 0 .
:e :hasValue 1 .
```

You can use a query with **group by** and **group_concat** to concatenate the variables together for each distinct value:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?value (group_concat(?variable) as ?variables) {
  ?variable :hasValue ?value 
}
group by ?value
```

```
-------------------------------
| value | variables           |
===============================
| 2     | "urn:ex:c urn:ex:a" |
| 1     | "urn:ex:e urn:ex:b" |
| 0     | "urn:ex:d"          |
-------------------------------
```